# Naming xml node based on value from DB column

Tags: sql, xml

Currently I have an xml structure that is built like this.

```
<Project>
  <ProjectAttribute>
    <AttributeId></AttributeId>
    <FieldName></FieldName>
    <Title></Title>
    <DisplayRow></DisplayRow>
    <DisplayColumn></DisplayColumn>
    <IsRequired></IsRequired>
    <RequiredErrorMessage></RequiredErrorMessage>
    <DevExpressControl>
      <DevExpressControlId></DevExpressControlId>
      <Class></Class>
      <ClientNamePrefix></ClientNamePrefix>
    </DevExpressControl>
    <DataType>
      <DataTypeId></DataTypeId>
      <Name></Name>
    </DataType>
  </ProjectAttribute>
</Project>
```

I want to rename ProjectAttribute with the value of FieldName.  I am unsure how to do this at the moment, seeing how when I try to put the value of that field into the XML Path, I get an error.

Here is what my sql looks like.

```
Set @output = (
        SELECT poa.AttributeId, pa.FieldName, pa.Title, poa.DisplayRow,
            poa.DisplayColumn, poa.IsRequired, pa.RequiredErrorMessage,
            (SELECT de.DevExpressControlId, de.Class, de.ClientNamePrefix
                FROM SCC_DevExpressControl de
                WHERE de.DevExpressControlId = pa.DevExpressControlId
                FOR XML Path(''), type) AS DevExpressControl,
            (SELECT dt.DataTypeId, dt.Name
                FROM SCC_DataType dt
                WHERE dt.DataTypeId = pa.DataTypeId
                FOR XML Path(''), type) AS DataType
        FROM SCC_ProjectOfficeAttribute poa
            LEFT JOIN SCC_ProjectAttribute pa ON poa.AttributeId = pa.AttributeId
        WHERE poa.OfficeId = @OfficeId
            AND poa.Status = 1
        ORDER BY poa.DisplayRow, poa.DisplayColumn
        FOR XML Path('ProjectAttribute'), type, Root('Project'))

    select @output
```

@OfficeId is just an int, and @output is simply the xml.  Where I am writing in the XML Path for ProjectAttribute is what I want to replace.  My question is how do I get that value in there?

UPDATE:  I am still somewhat at a loss.  I have tried moving things like AttributeId and FieldName into the main node itself for ProjectAttribute, but this does not really fulfill my requirements.